# Managing angularjs nested promises to build response back from the server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

Im building a response back from the server using angular in order to show private messages. So far i have this code which works fine but it doesnt look like using promises the correct way, specially for handling errors. Im wondering how im suppose to handle nested promises in a case like this using best practices?

```
function listenMessageSend(data) {

var imData = {
  message: data.data.id,
  sender: currentUser().id,
  reciever: $scope.reciever
}

Im.create(imData).then(function(im) {
  Message.update(im.data.message, {im: im.data.id}).then(function(msg) {
    User.get(msg.data.im.sender).then(function(sender) {
      msg.data.im.sender = sender.data;
      User.get(msg.data.im.reciever).then(function(reciever) {
        msg.data.im.reciever = reciever.data;
      });   
    });
    if (msg.data.im.sender === currentUser().id || msg.data.im.reciever === currentUser().id) {
      $scope.messages.push(msg.data);
    }
  })
});

};
```

Comment: Are you sure this works fine? the `if` condition is evaluated before `.sender` and `.receiver` are set in the promise callbacks!

Comment: .sender and .reciever already exist when Message.update() so it works fine

Comment: yes, that might be, but they have the "old" values in the `if` condition, as if `User.get` is only executed later. Not sure whether you wanted that. You should consider moving the if-statement before the `User.get(…)` call so that it gets clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get sender data at the same time you are getting receiver data. You shouldn't nest two promises that are contextually independent as it'd result in poor user experience, because you're waiting the "sender" response ends to issue the request that gets the "receiver" data, while the browser could perfectly deal with the two requests at the same time.

You should issue the two requests at the same time and wait for both to deal with related data. Like this:

```
Im.create(imData).then(function(im) {
  Message.update(im.data.message, {im: im.data.id}).then(function(msg) {
    var senderGet = User.get(msg.data.im.sender).then(function(sender) {
      msg.data.im.sender = sender.data;
    });
    var receiverGet = User.get(msg.data.im.reciever).then(function(reciever) {
      msg.data.im.reciever = reciever.data;
    });
    $q.all([senderGet, receiverGet]).then(function() {
      if (msg.data.im.sender === currentUser().id || msg.data.im.reciever === currentUser().id) {
        $scope.messages.push(msg.data);
      } 
    });
  })
});
```

Or another option if you believe it's more readable:

```
Im.create(imData).then(function(im) {
  Message.update(im.data.message, {im: im.data.id}).then(function(msg) {
    var senderGet = User.get(msg.data.im.sender);
    var receiverGet = User.get(msg.data.im.reciever);
    $q.all([senderGet, receiverGet]).then(function(response) {
      msg.data.im.sender = response[0].data;
      msg.data.im.reciever = response[1].data;      
      if (msg.data.im.sender === currentUser().id || msg.data.im.reciever === currentUser().id) {
        $scope.messages.push(msg.data);
      } 
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: Seems good. Would be better to deal with the callback hell i guess

Answer (score 0):

The `if` must stay inside the deeper promisse, because It will be resolved lastly:

```
User.get(msg.data.im.sender).then(function(sender) {
  msg.data.im.sender = sender.data;
  User.get(msg.data.im.reciever).then(function(reciever) {
    msg.data.im.reciever = reciever.data;
    if (msg.data.im.sender === currentUser().id || msg.data.im.reciever === currentUser().id) {
      $scope.messages.push(msg.data);
    }
  });   
});
```